# Google App Engine SOAP Not Appearing in phpinfo()

Tags: google-app-engine, soap

```
Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in ../libraries/Shipping/drivers/Shipping_usps.php on line 12
```

Using Google App Engine for PHP, I receive the error above when try to instantiate a SoapClient object. I've checked phpinfo() and the SOAP extension isn't showing up. When I deploy to production, it does show up, so I figure there's something that's causing the extension not to load locally. I run the dev server from the command line as opposed to the application on Mac OS.

GAE is up to date. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the bundled PHP interpreter that's included with the SDK, or your own local install?

Comment: I am using the interpreter that came with the SDK; although, I do have a local installation of PHP5.6~. I have not changed any settings or explicitly stated that I want GAE to use my local PHP during run time. Is there a way to see which interpreter is being used?